# When and how to use rel="canonical" for dynamic URL's

Tags: seo, canonical-url

We are creating dynamic URLs with a combination of service names and city names.
Below are the sample pages.

Please let us know in which page do we needs to add `rel="canonical"` and which link to add in canonical tag.

If city name is added in url the application shows all avalibale food service in given city & hence there are chances of getting duplicate contents are more.

If city name is not there in url it means it will list all food services across all cities.

- Page 1. `abc.com/food`
- Page 2. `abc.com/food/pune`
- Page 3. `abc.com/food/mumbai`

Do I needs to add

`<link rel="canonical" href="abc.com/food"/>` in Page 2 & Page 3

Or

- `<link rel="canonical" href="abc.com/food"/>` in Page 1,
- `<link rel="canonical" href="abc.com/food/pune"/>` in Page 2,
- `<link rel="canonical" href="abc.com/food/mumbai"/>` in Page 3

Comment: You would use a [canonical link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canonical_link_element) to indicate the preferred page for search engines to index if the other page(s) might be considered a duplicate. You have not explained how these pages are related and which one would be the canonical page.

Comment: See also: [What is duplicate content and how can I avoid being penalized for it on my site?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/35652/what-is-duplicate-content-and-how-can-i-avoid-being-penalized-for-it-on-my-site)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of simply listing "all food services across all cities" in the absence of a city name, I would personally add additional content to the general food page that you cannot find on pages that are city-specific.

Then I would add a canonical link to each page.

```
<link href="abc.com/food" rel="canonical" />
<link href="abc.com/food/pune" rel="canonical" />
<link href="abc.com/food/mumbai" rel="canonical" />
```

---

Here's an example from YellowPages.com:

- https://www.yellowpages.com/houston-tx
- https://www.yellowpages.com/houston-tx/restaurants

```
<link href="https://www.yellowpages.com/houston-tx" rel="canonical" />
<link href="https://www.yellowpages.com/houston-tx/restaurants" rel="canonical" />
```